# How does FD_ISSET work and what's wrong of my code

Tags: c, sockets, select

I have some confusion about how ***socket fd*** and the ***fd_set*** changed by **FD_ISSET** and how **FD_ISSET** can verify this ***socket fd*** including in the ***fd_set***. So, I did a small test.

```c
    int sock_fd = -1;
    fd_set read_set;
    while (sock_fd < 20)
    {
        printf("Init:           sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld\n", sock_fd, read_set);
        FD_ZERO(&read_set);
        printf("after FD_ZERO   sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld\n", sock_fd, read_set);
        FD_SET(sock_fd, &read_set);
        printf("after FD_SET    sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld\n", sock_fd, read_set);
        FD_ISSET(sock_fd, &read_set);
        printf("after FD_ISSET  sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld\n", sock_fd, read_set);
        FD_CLR(sock_fd, &read_set);
        printf("after FD_CLR    sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld\n", sock_fd, read_set);
        printf("***********************************\n");
        sock_fd++;
    }
```

This is my code. The regularity is clear. For each pair, the value of read_set is the value of sock_fd + 63, i.e. **read_set = sock_fd + 63**.
So, based on that, I can say the original value of **read_set is 63(111111)**. But I dont know why.
So, I decided to do the next test. I add some printf in my past demo.
This is the part of this code.

```c
 fd_set read_set;
    fd_set write_set;
    fd_set select_read_set;


    FD_ZERO(&read_set);
    FD_ZERO(&write_set);
    FD_ZERO(&select_read_set);
    printf("after FD_ZERO, read_set is %ld, write_set is %ld, select is %ld\n", read_set, write_set, select_read_set);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CLIENT_NUM; i++)
    {
        client_fd[i] = -1;
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    memset(&cli_addr, 0, sizeof(cli_addr));

     printf("111 sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld, write_set is %ld, select is %ld\n", read_set, write_set, select_read_set);
    sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("sock_fd is %d\n", sock_fd);
    if (sock_fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Fail to socket");
        exit(1);
    }


    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP);
    printf("222 sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld, write_set is %ld, select is %ld\n", read_set, write_set, select_read_set);

    unsigned int value = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *)&value, sizeof(value)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Fail to setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

     printf("333 sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld, write_set is %ld, select is %ld\n", read_set, write_set, select_read_set);
    serv_addr_len = sizeof(serv_addr);
    if (bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, serv_addr_len) < 0)
    {
        perror("Fail to bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(sock_fd, BACK_LOG) < 0)
    {
        perror("Fail to listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[1024];
    //max_fd = sock_fd;
    printf("PPP sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld, write_set is %ld, select is %ld\n", read_set, write_set, select_read_set);
    FD_SET(sock_fd, &read_set);
    printf("QQQ sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld, write_set is %ld, select is %ld\n", read_set, write_set, select_read_set);
```

The result makes me totally confused. This are sentenced printed on screen.

```c
after FD_ZERO, read_set is 31834128, write_set is 0, select is 0
111 sock_fd is -404688640, read_set is 16, write_set is 2147483583, select is 0
sock_fd is 3
222 sock_fd is 0, read_set is 140083558421840, write_set is -104, select is 1844674407370955161
333 sock_fd is 1, read_set is 2, write_set is 140083557848394, select is 4
PPP sock_fd is 20, read_set is 16, write_set is 140083557847575, select is 0
QQQ sock_fd is 0, read_set is 8, write_set is 3, select is 0
```

I cannot understand them. See my code, I did't nothing for **read_set** after FD_ZERO until FD_SET, but the **read_set** changed always. And even I never do anything for **write_set**, **select_read_set** these two fd_set, they changed.
I have no idea about these four questions:
1. How **FD_ISSET** judges a **fd** contained in the **fd_set**?
2. For these two tests, why the result are them? I described my confusion.
3. As for the second test, u can see the value of 'sock_fd' also be altered. I guess it must be changed by `bind()` and others functions. But I dont understand why the socket fd needs to be altered? Based on my thoughts, one socket fd is unique for a socket and this one will be keeped until close. 
4. Is the return value of `socket()`(the socket fd) is random? I cannot find some regulatrity of it.

Please, teach me or give me some hints. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet of code you have:

```
int sock_fd = -1;
... // stuff that doesn't modify sock_fd
FD_SET(sock_fd, &read_set);
```

.... but POSIX says (Emphasis added)

> **The behavior of these macros is undefined if the fd argument is less than 0** or greater than or equal to FD_SETSIZE, or if fd is not a valid file descriptor, or if any of the arguments are expressions with side-effects.

So you're doing something explicitly called out as undefined, which means the compiler and system is free to do anything in response.

You're also treating `read_set` like it was a `long int`, which it doesn't have to be, and when it's not, also causes undefined behavior because the `printf()` specifier doesn't match the corresponding argument. You do this too in the second code block. In addition, you have `printf()` calls where the number of format specifiers don't match the number of arguments, which is also undefined behavior.

So, basically, by breaking contract with the language and function API like you are, you can't expect any consistent or logical results.

Your compiler *should* be warning you about at least the problems with `printf()`. Are you not enabling warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for gcc or clang)? Not doing so is a huge mistake in C programming.

Comment: while, please ignore fd=-1. It is meaningless. And I also found I forgot a parameter to printf. 
This should be```printf("PPP sock_fd is %d, read_set is %ld, write_set is %ld, select is %ld\n", sock_fd, read_set, write_set, select_read_set); ```
In this case, the value of **sock_fd** never changed.
But the FD_ZERO doesn't work for sock_fd still, I dont know why.
And for **write_set** and **select_read_set**, I did nothing for them, their values still be altered, where I'm wrong?